# conditional formatting with checkboxes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, formatting, conditional-statements

Is there a way to format a checkbox so that when it is "checked", The data in the column beside it will be moved to another column?

Comment: if you wish data to be physically moved around you will need a script

Comment: Is there a way to move a whole row to the bottom of the page if box is checked

Comment: bottom? define bottom, there is a lot of things to be stated for it to be exact. bottom of the transferred column? bottom of the current column? Show a sample data and the outcome so that it will be easy to reproduce and no assumptions will be made.

Comment: @EmmaBourdeau Is that a new question entirely? Explain _in detail_ what the desired behavior is. The comments are not for extended discussion or new questions requiring different answers.

Comment: ok, I would just like to know how to grab more than just one row to the right of the box. for example grab row a,b,c,d and move them over

Comment: please show a visualization on your post.. add images of before and after so everyone can easily understand. @EmmaBourdeau

Comment: The question post should contain the problem you want to solve. [Edit] the question to describe your problem as best as you can. Be aware that too many edits will be seen as moving the goalpost, which would not be well-received. As it stands right now, I think the question lacks key details, as evidenced by your last comment and the fact that *both* of the current answerers on this question thought you were wanting to move a single cell. (For the record, I thought that too.) For more information, please read [ask].

Comment: I recommend this post to close and repost with a fully detailed question. Original post is already answered below by 2 answers.

Answer (score 0):

As player0 mentioned, for this to work, you need Google Apps Script's [Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet) with the help of [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events).

The code below should work on the sample data below.

#### Sample data:

[image: sample data]

#### Code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var range = e.range;
  var column = range.getColumn();
  // if edited data is in Sheet1 Column A and having value TRUE (checkbox ticked) 
  if (sheet.getName() == "Sheet1" && column == 1 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    // get 1 column to the right of checkbox and assign to dataValue
    var dataRange = range.offset(0, 1);
    var dataValue = dataRange.getValue();
    // get 3 columns to the right of dataValue and assign to transferToRange
    var transferToRange = dataRange.offset(0, 3);
    // set dataValue as value to transferToRange
    transferToRange.setValue(dataValue);
    // remove data from dataRange after
    dataRange.setValue("");
  }
}
```

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Note:

- Above code is just one of the many possible solutions you can create via Apps Script.
- Read [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) for more information.

#### References:

- [Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet)
- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Answer (score 0):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == 'Sheet1' && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.value == 'TRUE') {
    e.range.offset(0, 5).setValue(e.range.offset(0, 1).getValue());
    e.range.offset(0, 1).setValue('');
    e.range.setValue('FALSE');
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I missed the term "moved" and just copied the data. Thanks for pointing it out in your answer @Cooper.